# How to extract certain substrings from a string in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract some information from a parse exception message which looks like the following:

```
"Encountered " <FUNCNAME> "FF "" at line 1, column 22.
Was expecting:
    "DEF" ..."
```

From this message I would like to get the token encountered, in the case above it would be "FUNCNAME" and I would also like to get the expected token, again, in this case it would be "DEF".

```
String[] REGEX = { "Encountered \" <(.*)> ", "Encountered (.*)." };
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX[0]);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
System.out.println("Matched:  " + matcher.group(1));
```

I used the pattern above to get the encountered token (which works fine), but I am struggling to get the expected one because of the line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to slightly rework your regex pattern, and also use the dot all `(?s)` modifier when declaring the regex, so that `.*` can match across lines.

```java
String message = "\"Encountered \" <FUNCNAME> \"FF \" at line 1, column 22.\nWas expecting:\n\"DEF\" ...";
String regex = "(?s)\"Encountered \" <(.*?)>.*?Was expecting:\\s+\"(.*?)\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Matched: " + m.group(1) + ", " + m.group(2));
}
```

This prints:

```
Matched: FUNCNAME, DEF
```